# Installing chef-server in a docker container

Tags: chef-infra, docker, linux-containers

I have been trying to install Chef-Server in a Docker container and I am having some trouble. I am running a VM with an up to date version of Ubuntu 12.04 and latest install of Docker. I run a base Docker Ubuntu 12.04 container and install chef-server, version 11.0.12 and that goes well. The problem is running the required 'sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure' step after install. The setup freezes at

```
  * link[/opt/chef-server/init/rabbitmq] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/chef-server/service/rabbitmq] action create (up to date)
  * **ruby_block[supervise_rabbitmq_sleep] action run**
```

and I get a stacktrace.out of

```
**SystemExit: ruby_block[supervise_rabbitmq_sleep] (chef-server::rabbitmq line 161) had an error: SystemExit: exit**
/opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/runit/definitions/runit_service.rb:165:in `sleep'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/runit/definitions/runit_service.rb:165:in `block (3 levels) in from_file'
```

If anyone has experienced this and/or has any ideas I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There is an image available in the [docker registry](https://index.docker.io/u/base/chef-server/).

```
docker pull  base/chef-server
docker run -d -p 443:443 base/chef-server
```

The Dockerfile is available here:

- https://github.com/tmc/dockerfiles/tree/master/chef-server

Comment: how do I test once the container is up & running?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. Increasing shared memory made it disappear. Run a container with option: `--privileged` and before starting chef server, run:
`sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=1288490189` (for me 1288490189 bytes which is 1.2GB was enough).

The docker image suggested in Mark O'Connor answer did not work for me (Unable to start database connection), I tried also [cbuisson/chef-server](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/cbuisson/chef-server/) (was reconfiguring endlessly) and finally I came up with my own: [xmik/chef-server-docker](https://github.com/xmik/chef-server-docker) (used Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: how do I test once the container is up & running?

Comment: As far as I know, in Chef Server 11, you had to configure the first user through its website, which made it hard for testing. In Chef Server 12 you can use `chef-server-ctl user-create`. I now use Chef Server 12 together with berkshelf-api and perhaps you find this manual test helpful: [berkshelf-api-docker/test/run.sh](https://github.com/xmik/berkshelf-api-docker/blob/master/test/run.sh) (it uses different docker image with chef server).