# Unable to install chef-server on docker container

Tags: docker, chef-infra

I am unable to install chef-server (chef-server-core_12.0.8-1_amd64.deb) over a docker container (Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64).
When running chef-server-ctl reconfigure it fails with following error:

```
Error executing action run on resource 'execute[/opt/opscode/bin/private-chef-ctl start rabbitmq]'
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed

Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /opt/opscode/bin/private-chef-ctl start rabbitmq ----
STDOUT: warning: rabbitmq: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist
STDERR:
---- End output of /opt/opscode/bin/private-chef-ctl start rabbitmq ----
Ran /opt/opscode/bin/private-chef-ctl start rabbitmq returned 1
```

NOTE: Before starting installation , I have done following steps inside the container:

```
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -sf /bin/true /sbin/initctl
sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=17179869184
```

Is there any other work-around to get chef-server up on docker container.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing chef-server in a docker container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996427/installing-chef-server-in-a-docker-container)